# alternative for AIX route command in Redhat 7

Tags: redhat, aix

Migrating from AIX to Redhat Enterprise Linux 7. Can someone suggest alternative for AIX route command in RHEL 7.0.

AIX route command has -cloning option that should also be covered in the equivalent command in RHEL.

AIX:
route add -net 10.100.10.0 -netmask 255.255.255.0 10.100.11.1 -cloning

Comment: You can drop the `-cloning` option from the command. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.networkcomm/tcpip_routing_cloning.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can get route command in RHEL 7. Install the net-tools package.

```
yum install net-tools
```

Comment: route command is available in our RHEL 7. But -cloning parameter is not available